# PHP backend code running on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to create backend for a website. I successfully created it. It ran perfectly on the localhost. Now when I moved the code to the server, The php just doesn't work. It shows an empty white screen.

It takes an input and returns a JSON output. What could be the problem ?
I am using Amazon EC2 server.

Here is my php code :

```
<?php

    require_once('common/common_database.php');

    class user
    {
        public $id;
        public $fName;
        public $lName;
        public $sex;
        public $image;
        public $birthday;
        public $location;

        public function __construct($userId)
        {
            $this->id = htmlspecialchars ( $userId );
        }

        public function getDetails()
        {
            global $dbh;

            //getting user's first and last name
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` = :id;";
            $s = $dbh->prepare ( $query );
            $s->bindParam ( ":id" , $this->id );
            $s->execute (  );
            $r  =  $s->fetch (  );
            $this->fName  = htmlspecialchars( $r['firstName'] );
            $this->lName = htmlspecialchars ( $r['lastName'] );
            $this->location = htmlspecialchars (  $r['location'] );
            $this->image = htmlspecialchars ( $r['image'] );
            $this->birthday = htmlspecialchars ( $r['birthday'] );
            $this->sex = htmlspecialchars ( $r['sex'] );

        }
    }

    if ( isset($_GET['id']) )
    {
        $newUser = new user( $_GET['id'] ); 
        $newUser->getDetails();
    }
    else
    {
        $newUser = 0;
    }

    $output = json_encode ( $newUser );
    header('content-type: application/json');
    echo $output;
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: I would recommend starting by comparing your phpinfo() outputs. Sounds like a difference in configuration.

Comment: Please add error message that you get, or look at PHP error log

Comment: from where i can get the PHP error log ?

Comment: What I do when I just get white screens (usually on web hotels with wierd restrictions), I comment allt the code, and just run some of the code with a echo "do this show?" to find the place where it just gets white.

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch on error reporting for first:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

- Enable error reporting on top of page with code:

  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
- check your php ini setting. May be you need to enable pdo_mysql from php settings(php.ini).

Comment: I did set the errors ON. But couldn't catch any. Other than that, pro_mysql is activated. I guess this error is due to classes. Do we need to activate classes in php separately ?